# Appengine Django Template - Read template tags

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

**UPDATE 1**
ADDED UPDATED CODE

I have a django template on app engine.  Currently all my data is in several templates and I would like to read the templates off disk. Very easy, but I would like to get the values out of these templates in AppEngine.

eg. file : p1.html

```
{%block price%}$259{%endblock%}  
{%block buy%}http://www.highbeam.co.nz/store/index.php?route=product/product&path=6&product_id=116{%endblock%}  
{%block info%}http://www.inov-8.co.nz/oroc280.html{%endblock%}
```

Can I load and read these template into some value and go.

```
template['price']
```

which would be

> $259

I can easily inject data into the template, but I want to parse out the data between my block tags.

UPDATED 2
With the help of aaronasterling (THANKS) the final code is this.
Final code to get the value out of a Django template on app engine.
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), 'home/p2.html')

```
    file = open(path)
    entry = file.read()
    file.close()   
    entry = entry.replace("{% extends \"product.html\" %}","")   

    t = Template(entry) 

    product = {}
    for node in t.nodelist[0].nodelist  :   
       if hasattr(node, 'name'):
          product[node.name] = node.render(Context())
```

Comment: "all my data is in several templates" -  I don't understand this.  Why is data in a template?

Comment: It's like the best of todays MVC architecture mated with a web site from 1996.

Comment: It was far easy to put all the data in templates and put these in dropbox for my project managers to edit - only 15 pages of data, put all these in a DB was overkill.

Comment: You know what would have been even easier? An Excel file.  Managers Like excel.  Programmers also like excel because they can turn that into CSV.  DBA's like CSV's cause they can import that right into the database.

Comment: I still think this is a good way to go. Maybe I could render my data into a different template eg [{%block price%}{%end block%}] and go from there.

Comment: @John Ballinger. What would that do? Am I misunderstanding when I assume that the price is hard coded into that one template and will be the same regardless of the context passed to the renderer?

Comment: I have 15 templates named p1-p15.html.  Currently the project manager can just edit each template and update the correct data. In django each of these p1-p15.html extends the "product.html" which extends base.html.  So to render product 1, I simple render p1.html which has all the correct info to populate the product html page. Now I am doing a PDF print out and need the info in the files p1-p15.html hence the template parser.

Comment: A simple delimited text file would be much, much simpler than this.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, right now, hit another bump. Damn django. I am going to do that. Just make a simple text file for data....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you've shot yourself in the foot.  Lets just pretend we aren't to blame and fix it:

```
entry = """{%block price%}$259{%endblock%}  
{%block buy%}http://www.highbeam.co.nz/store/index.php?route=product/product&path=6&product_id=116{%endblock%}  
{%block info%}http://www.inov-8.co.nz/oroc280.html{%endblock%}   """

parsedentry = dict([(j[0].split(' ')[-1], j[-1]) for j in [i.partition("%}") for i in entry.split("{%endblock%}")] if j[0].split(' ')[-1]])

print parsedentry['price']
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!  I thought it might just come down to a token/string parser.  I did like aaronasterlings approach it was using djangos template parser.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 1** fixed to traverse the whole node tree.

**Update 2** Actually tested it so now it works.

Here's one way to do it.

```
from django.template import Template, Context

t = Template(template_string) # get it with open(filename).read() I guess


def get_block_contents(t, block_name, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = Context()
    stack = t.nodelist[:]
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        if hasattr(node, 'name') and node.name == block_name:
            return node.render(context)
        if hasattr(node, 'nodelist'):
            stack.extend(node.nodelist)
    return False # Or raise an error
```

Comment: Hi I know we are getting close. I am getting AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: @John, What version of django are you on?

Comment: If it's vanilla App engine, then most likely 0.96

Comment: Appengine is Python 2.5, I am not 100% sure which version of Django it is.